# SP Online - View files from one Site/DocLib/Folder to another Site/DocLib/Folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-document-library

Is there a way to view the docs from SiteA/DocLibA/FolderA in Site B.

I'm not looking to duplicate documents. I'd like a window from SiteB when I open DocLibB/FolderB to see all docs from SiteA/DocLibA/FolderA
Ideally it would be nice for it to look like it's a DocLib/Folder on SiteB.

Preferably not using SPD.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with [highlighted content web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd) to show content from another site collection. If you want to focus on a certain library, you may need to add a custom query to filter by the path. CAML or [KQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference) both works.

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thanks for that. I suspect I'm missing a key point in the step. What I'm trying to get is the items in the red box [link] (https://imgur.com/pJYxzQJ) on one site to be viewed on the second site in the blue box. The person in PMTestTeam has access to the folder Test-ES-Shared on the Enterprise Solutions site. Because of the selections I've added to the KQL, I was expecting only one document to show (Publish, Test-ES-Shared), Lockout.gif. When I change the KQL and remove my selections, I get a url link that takes me to the ES site. [link] (https://imgur.com/M2FwbbR)

Comment: @pobox90210 Only be able to provide some suggestions on building on query with try & error. According to your description, you may not need use AND, and the content class part and path part seem to be fine. If you want to filter with custom list column, you will need to do it with managed property. I guess the latter part in your query in first pic is not doable. Similar question:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/95b03a62-68ce-4f98-a811-05dc9baaf5d6/search-column-in-custom-list?forum=sharepointsearch

Comment: @pobox90210 Sorry for not being able to provide more help as we need to always try&error to fix the query. And one more thing, title column is not name column. They are different columns. Pay attention to that. You can edit the view and show title column for a more clear idea about it.